# Unit Test NSOperation?

Tags: iphone, ios, unit-testing, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I would like to test an `NSOperation` subclass. I tried to do this in my `SenTestCase` subclass:

```
- (void)setUp {
    [super setUp];

    _importQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

    [_importQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1];
    [_importQueue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];
}

- (void)tearDown {
    [_importQueue release];

    [super tearDown];
}

- (void)testSomeImport {
    ImportOperation *op = [[ImportOperation alloc] initWithFile:...];
    [_importQueue addOperation:op];
    [op setDelegate:self];
    [op release];
}

- (void)opDidFinish:(ImportOperation *)op {     // ImportOperation delegate method
    // Not getting called
}
```

But the tests finishes before the `NSOperation` finished executing, despite specifying `waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished`.

Any ideas of how to prevent the test from finishing before my operation completed?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to call `waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished` after you added the operation to the queue, not in `setUp`.